Resizing of Chart Gives Incorrect Values
I resized the chart to add other buttons and TextViews on the page, and in doing so have skewed the sizing incorrectly. Is there a fix to this? See attatched: The values from left to right are "30, 50, 70, 100"enter image description here
I have tried messing with the XML and changing the direct layout there, but haven't had any luck.
